# Difference between onclick() and .on('click',function())?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling
  $('.button').children().onclick(function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){
      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;

      });
    } // End if
  });
});




$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $('.button').children().on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

When i use onclick() function, on clicking the button there is no scrolling effect; it only jumps to article without any scrolling effect.

But when I use on('click',function()) there is a scrolling effect.

what is the difference between these two?

Comment: Answered a few times... here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: That question isn't the same. That's comparing `addEventListener()` to `onclick()`. This question is specifically about jQuery's methods.

Answer (score 1):

- `.onclick()` is a javascript function
- `.click()` and `.on("click")` are jQuery functions, and jQuery added some more features to its functions.